# Implementing sorting in symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using sonata-admin to provide user interface to configure some entities in database.

I need to build a custom symfony form, that will display relational data in a matrix-like way. Currently, my model relations look like this:

Campaign<-many-to-many->Filial<-one-to-many->WorkMode (Work mode is actually an intermediate table for Campaign<->Filial)

The idea is that when a user clicks 'edit' on entity in campaigns list in sonata, a generic sonata form is provided with a field Filials with type set to my custom form.

The form is supposed to look like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+
|"Filial Name"     |Day 1                           |Day N                   |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+
|{{filial[0].name}}|{{filial[0].(dayId=1).priority}}|{{filial[0].(dayId=n)...|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+
|{{filial[n].name}}|{{filial[n].(dayId=1).priroity}}|{{filial[n].(dayId=n)...|
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+
```

I assume that to achieve desired result, i'll have to implement some sorting of entities that are passed into form, but I have no idea how to approach this issue. Could you point me the right direction? A way to sort data in form type would be great. Any advice appreciated :)

Comment: Try with associations ordering: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html#ordering-to-many-associations